# web browsers showing completely random images on web pages

Tags: browser, webserver

A few months ago i started seeing some images on websites, which i almost daily visit, that seemed unusual with the rest of the content. This happened mostly when the page contained a handful of images.

At first it seemed odd but then i realized something is definitely wrong when adult material started appearing. And almost on all websites. I tried to investigate it by myself by opening up the inspection tools of the browsers. The urls of the images seemed fine. When I opened those urls in a separate tab i saw mixed results. Sometimes, the wrong unexpected image would appear and sometimes the correct one.

I understood it as some kind of an issue with the web browser i was using at the moment. I tried to observe this on other browsers and got the same thing.

After that i assumed it must be some kind of virus/malware/adware. But before confirming this i ran one more test.

As i said above, this issue is easily observed when websites show a number of images. so i searched for websites that list lots of images (cat pictures, car images etc). I found one and started browsing through all of its galleries one by one. The issue popped again. I asked one of my coworkers to do the same using his computer. And he too observed the same issue. Another confirmed it as well.

Now, one of the coworker is running a different OS than most of us. He had to re-install it a few days ago as well. So it cannot be the virus. Which led us to believe that the problem is probably with our ISP's servers. The cache servers or the cache software on those servers to be precise. I am planning on writing them an email about this. But i wanted to share this with superuser community and get some feedback first.

I have the screenshots with me as a proof. Please see them for yourself (first = 2 incorrect images, second = 1 incorrect image, third = correct images). I am looking for more ideas about the problem. Please feel free to share.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you use a different DNS server rather than letting your ISP resolve names?

Comment: @EBGreen i cannot use any DNS other my router (192.168.15.1). so i cannot confirm that.

Comment: I assume you have done a malware/virus scan?

Comment: If any of the machines are laptops, try going somewhere else and see if you get the same results. As long as the ISP is different where you try it at, you have functionally changed DNS servers that way to verify if the ISP is monkeying with it or not.

Comment: @EBGreen i cannot reproduce the issue today. neither my coworkers. this does not happen all the time but when it does, it is easy to trigger it.

Comment: The problem is with a common server somewhere between you and the page's server.  It's caching images improperly.  Probably this is your in-house gateway server.

Comment: @DanielRHicks this is exactly what i thought. i am sure the issue is with my ISP. i have already experienced some issues with them before.